# Invoke Spring security with RestTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am new to spring security and I am confused over how spring security works. I have a filter chain defined as follows:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/internal/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/http/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and my security config looks as follows:

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

<http entry-point-ref="aligneUnauthorisedEntryPoint" use-expressions="true" create-session="never">
    <!--<intercept-url pattern="/user/login" access="isAuthenticated()"/>-->
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/internal/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/http/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <custom-filter ref="loginFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
    <custom-filter ref="logoutFilter" position="LOGOUT_FILTER"/>
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
    <http-basic/>
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="aligneAuthenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="aligneUserAuthenticationProvider"/>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="loginFilter" class="com.altra.middleware.security.AligneAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="aligneAuthenticationManager"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="aligneAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="aligneAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/user/login"/>
</beans:bean>
```

When i am hitting the following URL from my browser:
**http://localhost:9099/jedi/rest/internal/main/dropdown**

I get the following error.

Secondly, same exception comes occurs when i try to invoke the service from another spring controller using `RestTemplate`.

> HTTP ERROR 503 Problem accessing /jedi/rest/internal/main/dropdown.
>   Reason:
>
> ```
> Full authentication is required to access this resource
> ```

where `/jedi` is the application context.

If i comment out `<intercept-url pattern="/rest/internal/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>` then the correct controller's method is called.

What is the significance of `access="isAuthenticated()"` ? We have this method overridden but it never gets called.

How should i go about this problem ?

Comment: Are you supplying credentials to the endpoint? `RestTemplate` does not forward credentials on automatically, it needs to be configured with what creds you want to send. As for the browser behavior, you have enough overridden here (your own authentication provider, failure handler, and success handler) that it could be a number of things. Can you simplify your configuration (for the purposes of investigation) and still produce the issue?

Comment: I am supplying credentials via `RestTemplate`. Question here is which method of which class will be called so that i can debug against it and find out. I had put breakpoint in `attemptAuthentication` and `authenticate` but it never came there.

Comment: What I'd recommend is simplifying your configuration, removing custom components, to get a better idea of what is causing the issue. It will be easier for others (including me) to understand your situation that way. attemptAuthentication is an abstract method, so I don't know which you are referring to, but if you mean UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, that's for form login, which I'm guessing your RestTemplate would not use (it's probably using Basic authentication). Try to narrow your question, and the community can be more helpful. Posting your sample to github can also help.

Comment: It turns out that for each `intercept-url`, you need to have a `bean` configured to handle `authentication`. When i added the same, all rest calls via `rest/internal` were intercepted and handled via my custom class for authentication/authorization. Just to add, each class defined needs to have a different way of authentication as we will be adding all authentication filters under the `authentication-manager`.